# Slicing edges out of a high dimensional polytope.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polytopes

Let us start in 3D. Say I give you a polytope cone and you slice one of its edges out, like in this picture:

[image]

(i.e. you grab a plane that passes through it's apex and cut off a single edge)

Let's make the problem even simpler. Say the cone is a simple cone, i.e. 3 faces, 3 edges and label the faces $f_1, f_2, f_3$.

The edges can be defined as the intersections of 2 faces $e_1 = f_1 \cap f_2$ and analogously for $e_2$. For shorthand let's say $e_{ij} = f_i \cap f_j$.

If the plane cuts off the edge $e_{23}$ then it means it intersects the cone into 2 edges, one by intersecting $f_2$ and one by intersecting $f_3$.

Now let's say we are in 4D.

An edge in 4D will be the intersection of 3 hyper planes. So let us say that $e_234$ is the edge that we are cutting from the simple cone. Let $p$  denote the new plane. The question is if you can generate a sequence of symbols containing $p$ so that every contiguous sequence of 3 elements in it is an edge of the poltyope cone (non encessarily exhaustive).

So for example, going back to 3D. The original cone was $123$ and after cutting it it became $12p3$ because $12$ is a valid edge, so are $2p, p3, 31$.

In 4D our plane generates 3 new edges, we know that it intersects the planes $2,3,4$. We are missing which other planes generate the newly introduced edges.

Am I correct to say that $23p45$ is the sequence of symbols that corresponds to the 3 new edges? such that $23p, 3p4, p45$ are the 3 edges in 4D?

Comment: The equivalent in 4D of cutting an edge in 3D would be to cut  a plane, i.e. a 2D "edge", rather than to cut a 1D edge, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni A polytope cone, regardless of the dimension will always have a 0-facet (the apex) and some number of 1-facets (edges) all connected to that apex.

What I am interested in is what happens when a new plane comes and excludes a single edge (1 facet) out of the polytope, which produces a new polytope with strictly more edges than before. i.e. I am certain I want to cut out an edge, not a 2 facet.